# DD-WRT wget returns a cached file

Tags: bash, caching, wget, dd-wrt

I'm developing an installer for my YAMon script for *WRT routers  (see http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=289324).

I'm currently testing on a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND with DD-WRT v3.0-r28647 std (01/02/16). Like many others, this firmware variant does not include `curl` so I (gracefully) fall back to a `wget` call. But, it appears that DD-WRT includes a cut-down version of `wget` so the -C and --no-cache options are not recognized.

Long & short, my `wget` calls insist on downloading cached versions of the requested files.

BTW - I'm using:   `wget "$src" -qO "$dst"`
where `src` is the source file on my remote server and `dst` is the destination on the local router

So far I've unsuccessfully tried to:
 1. append a timestamp to the request URL
 2. reboot the router
 3. run `stopservice dnsmasq` & `startservice dnsmasq`
None have changed the fact that I'm still getting a cached version of the file.

I'm beating my head against the wall... any suggestions? Thx!

Al

Comment: What if you explicitly `rm` the file & then initiate a fresh `wget`? I am not sure, I have understood your question.

Comment: Cached by what? `wget` doesn't cache anything on its own; there must be something going on upstream. But where?

Comment: No idea where things are getting cached but it is clear (to me at least) that they are.  I update the file on my remove server, delete the destination directory on the router and then run wget... an out-of-date file is written to the router?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but a seemingly viable workaround...

After a lot of experimentation, I found that `wget` seems to always return the latest version of the file from the remote server *if* the extension on the requested file is '.html'; but if it is something else (e.g., '.txt' or '.sh'), it does not.

I have no clue why this happens or where they are cached.

But now that I do, all of the files required by my installer have an html extension on the remove server and the script saves them with the proper extension locally. (Sigh...several days of my life that I won't get back)

Al

Answer (score 1):

I had the same prob. While getting images from a camera the HTTP server on the camera always send the same image.

```
wget --no-http-keep-alive ..
```

solved my problem

and my full line is

```
wget --no-check-certificate --no-cache --no-cookies --no-http-keep-alive $URL -O img.jpg -o wget_last.log
```